# jQuery widget: How to keep track of the instances?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a jQuery widget that may create many instances; how can I keep track of all the instances?

Comment: You want references to the `wideget` object, of the elements it's creating, like a container?

Answer (score 0):

@Nick, assume it is sort of the dialog plugin and I want to keep track of the instances my plugin has created in order to accomplish operations such as deletion of all the instances at once or counting of all the instances, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Already found a solution at http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/